# Why is my installed Node package not found

Tags: node.js

I want to use the upper-case package in Node.js.

I ran this:

```
C:\Users\yourName\folderName>npm install upper-case
```

and got this:

```
C:\Users\yourName\folderName>npm install upper-case
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\yourName\folderName\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\yourName\folderName\package.json'
npm WARN nodeTutorials No description
npm WARN nodeTutorials No repository field.
npm WARN nodeTutorials No README data
npm WARN nodeTutorials No license field.

+ upper-case@2.0.1
added 2 packages from 2 contributors and audited 2 packages in 0.747s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Then I created a file with this code:

```
var http = require('http');
var uc = require('upper-case');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write(uc("Hello"));
  res.end();
}).listen(8081);
```

Then I called my code but got this error:

```
C:\Users\yourName\folderName\demo_uppercase.js:5
  res.write(uc("Hello"));
            ^

TypeError: uc is not a function
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\yourName\folderName\demo_uppercase.js:5:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:748:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:115:17)
```

Why is uc not found?

Comment: Did you check to see if it was added in the package.json file? Did you install it in the correct folder?

Comment: Why are you using a module? You have a native function for this: `str.toUpperCase()`. Just try `"Hello".toUpperCase()`.

Comment: It doesn't seem like any flag was added to save to `package.json`. My recommendation is go to the npmjs page for the package and/or the Github project and see examples of how to use it

Comment: I don't have a package.json file, only a package-lock.json.  It is in the correct folder.

Comment: I'm using a module because I'm running through a node tutorial to get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This package exports an uppercase function.

Do it like

```
import { upperCase } from "upper-case";

upperCase("string"); //=> "STRING"
```

OR

```
var uc = require('upper-case');

uc.upperCase("string"); //=> "STRING"
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to Help. Mind Accepting the answer ?